# Printing the value of a signal

Tags: vhdl

Is there a way to print the value of a signal using `REPORT`?
I've seen `report "" integer'image(a)` for integers. Is there an equivalent for signals?
Thanks

Comment: When you test bench your code, that shows you the states of all the signals your interested in. Or you could connect the signal a test pad output of the FPGA to see how it is responding. Why are you wanting to see a signal?

Comment: But what if i have deeply nested components

Comment: Then i will need to add to the ports in order to see the signal value?

Comment: What's stopping you test benching the component you're having the issue with? You only need to test bench the component you want to look at. As much to save processing time as anything else.

Comment: For example if i have an entity A which instantiates component A, inside component A instantiates component B, how can i see the signal values of component B?

Comment: Its alot of work to rewrite the testbench for every signal component!

Comment: Then you have to weigh up: is it easier to test bench the component, or bring the signal out to the level your test bench is working at. Depending on the test bench, I'd say it's easier to bring the signal to the test bench level, as that avoids having to write a new test bench from scratch.

Comment: Thats very sucky, why they dont have a feature like this?
Seems very unneccesary!

Comment: I would expect this is possible, it certainly is in Verilog, though VHDL has a rather more pedantic philosophy. Additionally a typical simulator with a wavefirm viewer will let you drill down and see anything, though that is not the same as generating a textual log.

Answer (score 1):

VHDL can print any sort of text strings and also read and write files (using STD.TEXTIO) with that text.  It can convert data from one format to another using built in attributes of types or signals and through utility funcitons.

E.g. You can also define your own functions for formatting that returns characters and strings.  Some standard library functions are provided for this too.  Examples of this at the bottom.

Strings concatenate just like signals using & (ampersand)

```
...
signal x : std_logic_vector;
begin

--Some examples....
report integer'image(conv_integer(unsigned(x), x'length)) severity note;
--or
report std_logic_vector'image(x);
--or
report "0x" & to_hstring(x);
...
```

For a more complete example, take this excerpt from https://github.com/the-moog/vhdl_modular_blocks/blob/master/utils.vhd that I wrote some years ago.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.std_logic_arith.all;

package utils is


  --! @brief Return the N'th nibble (4 bits) of a std_logic_vector as a hex digit in ASCII
  function to_hex(v : std_logic_vector; nibble : integer) return character;
  
  --! @brief Return a std_logic_vector representation of the ASCII position of a character
  function char2byte(c : in character) return std_logic_vector;
  
  --! @brief Convert a string into an arbitrary length std_logic_vector of string'length * 8
  procedure str2bitstring(s : string; signal v : out std_logic_vector); 
  
  --! @brief Return a new string with all the characters of the supplied string in upper case
  function ucase(v : string) return string;
  
  --! @brief Return a new string with all the characters of the supplied string in lower case
  function lcase(v : string) return string; 
  
  --! @brief Return the supplied character mapped to upper case
  function ucase(c : character) return character;
  
  --! @brief Return the supplied character mapped to lower case
  function lcase(c : character) return character;
  
  --! @brief Pad a short string to n characters length with a given character
  function pads(constant s : string; length : positive; padchar:character:=' ') return string;
  
  --! @brief Returns a new string with a given character replaced
  function str_replace_char(constant s : string; constant find : character; constant replace : character) return string;  
  
  --! @brief Limit strings to 0..9 and A..Z with underscore
  function str_simplify(constant s : string) return string;
end package;


package body utils is  
  
  function pads(constant s : string; length : positive; padchar:character:=' ') return string is
  variable temp : string(1 to length);
  begin 
    if length > s'length then
      temp(1 to s'length) := s;
      temp(s'length + 1 to length) := (others => padchar);
    else
      temp := s(1 to length);
    end if;
    return temp;
  end function;
  
  function str_replace_char(constant s : string; constant find : character; constant replace : character) return string is
   variable temp : string(s'range);
  begin                           
    for n in s'range loop
      if s(n) /= find then
        temp(n) := s(n);
      else
        temp(n) := replace;
      end if;
    end loop;
    return temp;
  end function;           
  
  function str_simplify(constant s : string) return string is
    variable temp : string(s'range);           
    variable us : unsigned(7 downto 0);
  begin        
    for n in temp'range loop 
      temp(n) := ucase(s(n));
      us := conv_unsigned(character'pos(temp(n)), us'length); 
      if not ((us >= character'pos('A') and us <= character'pos('Z')) or
        us = character'pos('_') or
        (us >= character'pos('0') and us <= character'pos('9'))) then
        temp(n) := '_';
      end if;
    end loop;
    return temp;
  end function;

  function ucase(v : string) return string is
  variable temp : string(v'range);
  begin
    for n in temp'range loop      
      temp(n) := ucase(v(n));
    end loop;
    return temp;
  end function; 
  
  function lcase(v : string) return string is
  variable temp : string(v'range);
  begin
    for n in temp'range loop
      temp(n) := lcase(v(n));
    end loop;
    return temp;
  end function;   
  
  function ucase(c : character) return character is
  variable temp : character;
  variable us : unsigned(7 downto 0);
  begin
    us := conv_unsigned(character'pos(c), us'length); 
    if us >= character'pos('a') and us <= character'pos('z') then
      temp := character'val(conv_integer(unsigned(std_logic_vector(us) and not x"20")));
    else
      temp := c;
    end if;

    return temp;
  end function; 
  
  function lcase(c : character) return character is
  variable temp : character;
  variable us : unsigned(7 downto 0);
  begin
    us := conv_unsigned(character'pos(c), us'length); 
    if us >= character'pos('A') and us <= character'pos('Z') then
      temp := character'val(conv_integer(unsigned(std_logic_vector(us) or x"20")));
    else
      temp := c;
    end if;

    return temp;
  end function; 

  --Convert a nibble of a std_logic_vector to a hex digit
  function to_hex(v : std_logic_vector; nibble : integer) return character is
  variable bcd : unsigned(3 downto 0);
  variable len : integer := ((v'length / 4) + 1) * 4;
  variable extend : std_logic_vector(0 to len - 1);
  begin
    extend := ext(v, len);
    bcd := unsigned(extend(nibble to nibble+3));
    if bcd < 10 then
      return character'val(conv_integer(bcd) + character'pos('0'));
    else
      return character'val(conv_integer(bcd) + character'pos('A'));
    end if;
  end function;

  --Convert a character to a std_logic_vector (ASCII encoded)
  function char2byte(c : in character) return std_logic_vector is
  begin
    return std_logic_vector(conv_unsigned(character'pos(c), 8));
  end function;

  --Convert a string of characters into a string of bits (ASCII encoded)
  procedure str2bitstring(s : string; signal v : out std_logic_vector) is
  variable temp : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
  variable count : integer := 0;
  begin
    for n in s'low to s'high loop
      temp := std_logic_vector(conv_unsigned(character'pos(s(n)), temp'length));
      v((count * 8) + 7 downto (count * 8)) <= temp;
      count := count + 1;
    end loop;
  end procedure;

end package body;
```